# Record audio loopback from audio output device on Snow Leopard and later

Tags: macos, audio

I would like to programatically record audio loopback from audio output device(NOT input) on OSX 10.6+ in C/C++/ObjC.
It should capture audio output(PCM raw data) from all processes instead of a specific process like SoundFlower.
Any idea on this?

Comment: Any luck finding answers to this?