# How to record system background sound (loopback recording) with Audio Queue in Mac OS?

Tags: audioqueue

Using audio queue we can record the sound from system's default device such as microphone. I just want to record the background sound (the buffer of the sound card device) of the system not want to open microphone.

Should I use AudioQueueNewOutput?

I want to record the Built-in Output of the audio device(loopback recording).

Comment: [Here is a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17195701/record-audio-loopback-from-audio-output-device-on-snow-leopard-and-later). It's seems hard to implement.